# Does FreeBSD 9.0 installs with multi-core support by default?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

Planning to install FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE amd64.

Should I re-compile kernel after installation for multiple CPU cores support?
or SMP-kernel comes in default installation?

Comment: What do you think? What percentage of 64-bit machines do you think have only a single core these days?

Comment: What do I think? I think of you in a filthy language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It should support SMP by default](http://www.freebsd.org/releases/9.0R/hardware.html#PROC-AMD64), and [has been since freebsd 3/4/5](http://people.freebsd.org/%7Efsmp/SMP/getstarted.html). I don't even find smp as an option in the kernel config part of the handbook, so its probably something all kernels will have.